# Python 3 запоминание пути файла

Tags: python-3.x

Есть кнопка, при нажатии на которую просит выбрать папку

```
def savefiles():
global dst
dst = askdirectory()
b1 = ttk.Button(text='...', command=savefiles, width=3)
```

Дальше у меня идёт распаковка .zip файла по пути, который выбрал пользователь(dst)

```
class Razarx(Thread):
def __init__(self, fantasy_zip, dst):
    Thread.__init__(self)
    self.fantasy_zip = fantasy_zip
    self.dst = dst

def run(self):
    """Запуск потока"""
    print('\n\nExtracting...')
    fantasy_zip = self.fantasy_zip
    dst = self.dst
    fantasy_zip.extractall(self.dst)
    fantasy_zip.close()
    print('\nExtraction Complete')

def zeb(urls):
url = 'https://getfile.dokpub.com/yandex/get/https://yadi.sk/d/z_q5y3OkvBwJtg'
file_name = "Project City.zip"
thread = DownloadThread(url, file_name)
thread.start()`
```

При перезаходе в программу приходится постоянно заново выбирать путь, иначе выдаст ошибку с переменной dst.
Можно как-то сделать запоминание пути, чтобы выбрать один раз и при последующем перезаходе в программу заново его не выбирать.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Есть такая штука как: configparser, для чего она нужна?

Она нужна для того чтобы читать и записывать файлы конфигураций.

Пример файла конфигураций:

```py
[Files settings]
path = C:/User/...
```

Как создавать такие файлы:

```py
try:
    import configparser
except ImportError:
    import ConfigParser as configparser

def createConfig(path):
    """
    Create a config file
    """
    config = configparser.ConfigParser()
    config.add_section("Path to files")
    config.set("Path to files", "font", "Courier")


    with open(path, "w") as config_file:
        config.write(config_file)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    path = "settings.ini"
    createConfig(path)
```

Удалять, изменять и тд:

```py
import configparser
import os

def crudConfig(path):
    """
    Create, read, update, delete config
    """
    if not os.path.exists(path):
        createConfig(path)

    config = configparser.ConfigParser()
    config.read(path)

    # Читаем некоторые значения из конфиг. файла.
    font = config.get("Settings", "font")
    font_size = config.get("Settings", "font_size")

    # Меняем значения из конфиг. файла.
    config.set("Settings", "font_size", "12")

    # Удаляем значение из конфиг. файла.
    config.remove_option("Settings", "font_style")

    # Вносим изменения в конфиг. файл.
    with open(path, "w") as config_file:
        config.write(config_file)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    path = "settings.ini"
    crudConfig(path)
```